# WPF - Ability to group multiple controls together and show one of several 'pages'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

Sorry for the weird title.

Let's say I have a combobox with 3 values, A,B,C.

If 'A' is selected, I want to display a certain set of controls. If 'B' is selected, I want to show a different set of controls, but over the exact same spot in the ticket.

Basically like a tab control, but I don't want the tabs visible - but I need certain 'pages', and depending on a bound value, to display one of those pages.

I know that I can create separate userControls and set the visibility of each based on the value of the combobox, but then in my wpf designer, I am stuck seeing all of the possible 'pages' at the same time.

Is this possible to do in WPF? Thanks.

Comment: How about binding Visible of whatever the natural container is to a particular value of the combo box with a ValueConverter?

Comment: That would work, but as I stated above, the designer would not be an accurate representation of the screen. I.e. there could be 10 controls of which only 1 would be visible at any given time and the rest wouldn't take up any space.

Comment: Have them all be visiable in design mode. Setup up bool/Visible properties for the Binding. In design mode, have them all return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a very similar situation recently. My solution was to use a Frame control. The [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) control would allow various [Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#CreatingAXAMLPage) to be loaded within. Each Page may contain a different set of controls, just like the main window can. If navigation is disabled on the Frame, it should be pretty close to what you are looking for. Sample Xaml:

```
 <Frame Name="thisFrame" Width="250" Height="400" 
  NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

Within your event handler for changing the combo box:

```
thisFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new PageClassName() );
```

This will make the Frame display the selected Page. Optionally you can provide parameters here to set default states for the UI controls within your new page. If you pass an object this way, you can bind the UI controls to the object to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks very much for your fast response! I did just find out that DevExpress 11 also has an option to hide the actual tabs. I will certainly try out your solution though, thanks again.

Comment: Best of luck to you! If your solution ultimately works, I would encourage you to post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: It does indeed work! I will post a sample on Monday. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample solution. Note that it uses DevExpress 11, which has the functionality to remove tab headers from a tab control. (Where UsePage1 and UsePage2 are booleans in my viewmodel. Only one can be true at a given time).

```
<DXTabControl SelectedIndex="0"  Width="Auto" >
<DXTabControl.View>
   <TabControlMultiLineView HeaderLocation="None" />
 </DXTabControl.View>
<DXTabItem IsSelected="{Binding Path=UsePage1}" >
</DXTabItem>
<DXTabItem IsSelected="{Binding Path=UsePage2}" >
</DXTabItem>
</DXTabControl>
```